# check input of textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working with asp.net and I'm using textboxes for user input. I want to make sure that the user enters digits only. I don't want to use validation controls. If maybe somehow I could use the ASCII value of the text entered by the user to compare whether it's an alphabet or not using C#. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, this is what the validation controls are good at, in this case the RegularExpressionValidator would be a good candidate.

Another option would be to use the [MaskedEdit](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/maskededit/maskededit.aspx) Ajax Extender.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" 
onkeypress="return (event.keyCode>= 48 && event.keyCode<= 57)" />
```

See [example](http://jsfiddle.net/aKYXR/)

or

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
       onkeypress="return (event.keyCode>= 48 && event.keyCode<= 57)" />
```

include period `.` in the range if it's required.